# Should I use ZimageZ in Xubuntu xfce to store my screenshots?

Tags: xfce, screenshot, online-storage

`xfce4-screenshooter` is offering to upload your screenshots automatically to zimagez.com but how long will they keep your screenshots there?

See this [article about the tool](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/06/new-xfce4-screenshooter-160-rocks.html) on webud8.org

If it is **not** stored "forever", it would be an unreliable way of sending someone your screenshot.

Comment: Ubuntu/xfce has nothing to do with when it gets deleted so this seems off topic to me. The only one that can answer this is zimagez. They have a twitter account. Ask them what 'used' means in `(Pictures stored online as long as they are used).` in their `how it works` section.

Comment: don't understand, why it is closed. the FAQ sais "Services provided by Ubuntu" and the `xfce4-screenshooter` is standard in Xubuntu, so is the ZimageZ too

Comment: zimagez is NOT a service provided by ubuntu. It is a service provided by zimagez @rubo77

Comment: I edited the title, does it fit now? I think this is **very** important for the users of the screenshot service in Xubuntu

Comment: @rubo77 - the revised question is now a "debate" style question which would encourage discussion.  As such it is not a good fit with the Q&A style on AU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From their [FAQ](http://faq.zimagez.com/question-22.html)(roughly translated):

*"Only anonymous images that have been inactive for several months (thumbnails not clicked) are automatically deleted, so there is no risk to see your collection go up in smoke :)"*

You would probably have to contact them directly to get more specific answers.

Comment: So this is not reliable at all!!! I will only use it for unimportant stuff then!

Comment: Better translation: "Only ANONYMOUS images that are inactive for several months (not clicked thumbnails) are automatically erased, so there is no risk of seeing your collection in smoke :)". If you sign in to upload, your images are not deleted.